# Pass forward a map iterator in rust

Tags: rust

Conceptually, I'd like to have an "extended" HashMap class that I'll call a FrequencyTable

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct FrequencyTable<K,V>(HashMap<K,HashSet<V>>);
```

I'd like to define a "default" that goes over the `HashMap` member.

My first attempt was

```
impl<K,V> std::iter::IntoIterator for FrequencyTable<K,V> {
    type Item = (K,HashSet<V>);
    type IntoIter = std::collections::hash_map::Iter<'static, K, HashSet<V>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> std::collections::hash_map::Iter<'static, K, HashSet<V>> {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}
```

which complains because `K` and `V` need lifetime bounds so I tried

```
impl<K,V> std::iter::IntoIterator for FrequencyTable<K,V> where K: 'static, V:'static {
    type Item = (K,HashSet<V>);
    type IntoIter = std::collections::hash_map::Iter<'static, K, HashSet<V>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> std::collections::hash_map::Iter<'static, K, HashSet<V>> {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}
```

which then says `expected parameter 'k', found '&K' ...` But adding `&`s to the variables didn't solve the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `IntoIterator::into_iter` not `Iter::iter` from the inner sources:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct FrequencyTable<K,V>(HashMap<K,HashSet<V>>);

impl<K,V> std::iter::IntoIterator for FrequencyTable<K,V> {
    type Item = (K,HashSet<V>);
    type IntoIter = std::collections::hash_map::IntoIter<K, HashSet<V>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0.into_iter()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=98aec8a317b37ce0319b9a67663dcb8e)

Notice that `Iter` yields `&T` and takes `&self`, while `IntoIter` yields `T` and takes `self`. So you don't need to deal with the lifetimes for this `IntoIter` implementation.

Comment: what we need https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=807d10734ca80d4df1c9ecc3f480c7db

Comment: @Stargateur had no clue it was in nightly already! oh boy, that is exciting indeed :)